# Can I set a timeout for a hostname in ~/.ssh/config?

Tags: ssh

If I create a host alias in ~/.ssh/config like the following one:

```
host myhost
    hostname myhost.mysubnet.mynet.com
    hostname myhost.mynet.com
    user igordcard
```

I am able to connect to myhost.mysubnet.mynet.com perfectly using `ssh myhost`. However, when this hostname is not reachable, it will never connect. Is there a way to set a timeout for the first hostname so it can automatically try the second one, and so on? If not, is there any other way for achieving almost the same effect?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this [superuser question](http://superuser.com/questions/416429/network-dependent-ssh-config) might get your started.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't found that page yet. So, it seems that the only way to keep using the same command, "ssh myhost", is to auto-detect the network and act accordingly, seamlessly switching ssh config files.

Comment: I will accept the first answer that says a timeout can be set for the ssh config hostnames, otherwise (and if it takes some weeks) I'll accept a future answer by you damienfrancois.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer reflects the exact implementation of the workaround I decided to do, based on the page link provided by damienfrancois and the answer by pcm which is inside that page.

Under `~/.bashrc` I've added the following at the end:

```
nets=$(hostname -I)

if [[ "$nets" == *192.168.* ]]
then
  alias ssh='ssh -F .ssh/config.alt'
fi
```

Which gets the list of network interfaces' addresses connected and then tries to match a segment of a specific network address with that list to check if we are connected to some network and, if so, an alias for `ssh` is set to use an alternative ssh config file.

This workaround is obviously subject to failure, for instance when the host moves from network to network but these networks share the same network prefix. However, for my specific case (and many others), this is enough.